# Android Studioで初めに表示させるファイルがAndroidになってしまったのを、Projectに直したい。

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Flutterでアプリ開発をするのにAndroid Studioを使用しています。
Android StudioのUpdateを行ったところ、新規プロジェクトを作成する際や、既存のプロジェクトを開いた際など、
今まで、Project内のlibフォルダがデフォルトで表示されていたのですが、Androidがデフォルトの設定になってしまい困っています。
Projectに変更することはできるのですが、いちいち変更を直すのが嫌です。
Projectをデフォルトにする方法がありましたら、お教えください。よろしくお願いします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudioを、前回のプロジェクトを開くにしておくと、
AndroidStudioを閉じる際に一番最後に保存した内容で次回開かれるので、
初期設定にもよりますが、
閉じる時にprojectにした状態で保存して閉じたらいかがでしょう？